# "errorMessage": "Unexpected token in JSON" $ENVIRONMENT_ID/nodes

Tags: curl

So I'm here trying to learn Kaleido platform but
unable to try out an automated POC for myself.

I've got all my variables ready...

```
echo $CONSORTIUM_ID
u0n2ntzvyy
echo $ENVIRONMENT_ID
u0h47hwa69
echo $MEMBERSHIP_ID
u0pe8jgwom
```

but when i make the call i get...

```
curl -X POST -H "$HDR_AUTH" -H "$HDR_CT"  -d "{ 'name': 'suppliernode2', 'membership_id': 'u0pe8jgwom' }" "$APIURL/consortia/$CONSORTIUM_ID/environments/$ENVIRONMENT_ID/nodes" | jq

{
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token in JSON"
}
```

As you can see I've resorted to hard coding of some things.

The api documentation is not clear what fields need to be including to create a node from the REST api
http://console.kaleido.io/docs/docs/api_reference/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the post.

I think an important clarification here is that if you want to pass the body of your REST call as multi-line JSON, then you will need to use double quotes to escape and then double quotes within the body for the fields and values - e.g.

`CONSORTIUM=$(curl -H "$HDR_AUTH" -H "$HDR_CT" -s "$APIURL/consortia?name=api101" | jq -r ".[0]._id")
curl -H "$HDR_AUTH" -H "$HDR_CT" -s -d "{ \
    \"name\": \"Sample Environment\", \
    \"provider\": \"geth\", \
    \"consensus_type\": \"poa\" \
  }" "$APIURL/consortia/$CONSORTIUM/environments" | jq`

However, if you prefer to use single-line for the body of the call, then you should escape with single quotes and use double quotes within the body of the call - e.g.

`curl -X POST -d '{"membership_id":"abcde12345", "name":"BANK A node"}' -H "$HDR_AUTH" -H "$HDR_CT" "$APIURL/consortia/{consortia_id}/environments/{environment_id}/nodes" | jq`

The API 101 tutorial uses the multi-line approach for the examples - http://console.kaleido.io/docs/docs/api101/

The Understanding the Kaleido API elects for the single-line demonstration - http://console.kaleido.io/docs/docs/api/